# How to populate dropdown list in bootstrap using sql

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could anyone helps me how to populate the dropdown list in bootstrap using the SQL table, basically I want the dropdown list to be populated with values from SQL tables. This is how my HTML code looks like

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Oblik organizacije
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Type1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Type2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Type3</a></li>
    </ul>
 
</div>
```

So I want these values Type1, Type2, Type3 be populated with values from tblType

Comment: it's difficult to determine how familiar you are with ADO.NET and c#, and so the answer could become quite instructive and verbose.  You should provide some sort of code relating your attempt to do this work, otherwise I think it's too broad a question - as this could easily become a back and forward discussion board.

Comment: I think that is the problem, that I have created dropdown in bootstrap but I dont know what to do in C# so that this dropdown get populated

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c# , you could simply use the foreach loop :

```
@foreach (var x in YOUR_ARRAY)
{<li>@x</li>}
```

**Update :**

using a Model, inside your controller that is called for the view :

```
var TypeList = new tblTypeEntities();

ViewBag.TypeList = TypeList.tblType.ToList();

return View();
```

Inside your view :

```
@{   
   var TypeList = ViewBag.TypeList;
}
```

Then use the foreach loop :

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var x in TypeList)
    {<li>@x.YOUR_TABLE_FILED_NAME </li>} 
</ul>
```

hop that could help you

Comment: I'm using C# but I'm new in this, so I just need to populate dropdown with data from sql table

Comment: did you create a Model for your tblType ? if not you could check this topic it will be helpful : shorturl.at/fxCU4

Comment: Yes, I do have created Model for tblType. How can I use that